# Blocking Configuration Matrix jobs based on certain number of failures

Tags: jenkins

I'm using the Configuration Matrix feature of Jenkins to run a bunch of builds. I have two axes, for a total of about 20 build combinations. Some of the builds fail more frequently than others, and I'd like to dynamically exclude certain builds based on the number of consecutive failures, and disable them in the Matrix.

I've seen the Combination Filter feature of the Matrix configuration, and I was thinking that I could have a simple Groovy snippet that would check the failure rate, and possibly exclude particular items from future builds. I could of course maintain this information manually in a file somewhere, but since Jenkins already has that metadata, I'm wondering if I can somehow make it available to the Combination Filter.

Is the Combination Filter the right tool for this job? I'm open to any suggestion that would accomplish the dynamic exclusion of Matrix jobs based on consecutive failures. Thanks.

Comment: The combination filter would work, but you'd have to write your own plugin, or have your own system of querying Jenkins about the number of failures via the API, and using something like the `groovy` CLI command, or Job DSL plugin to update the job configuration. Alternatively, you could look at using the [Matrix Combinations Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-combinations-parameter) to trigger builds.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/matrix+groovy+execution+strategy+plugin) and a Groovy script, and it did the trick.

Comment: Who knew there were so many matrix axis plugins? Nice.